Connecting a Router with console to usb cable in system terminal
While running the command screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 terminal goes blank.
What i have tried:
Once i connected the console cable with the router and my system,
Am checking the usb port is available in my system and accessable by
$ ls -l /dev/*USB*  
/dev/ttyUSB0
$ dmesg 
...
[22726.984409] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[22727.133473] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303, bcdDevice= 4.00
[22727.133484] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[22727.133487] usb 3-3: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[22727.133489] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[22727.173700] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[22727.173713] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[22727.176639] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[22727.176657] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[22727.177713] usb 3-3: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
...

$ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
[ERROR: Terminal goes blank]
What i need to achive:
i need to access the router in terminal.
I have found this manual for stty to configure the serial port. But am not sure how to configure it.
